# Sending Arabic Characters via AJAX not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8

I am trying to send a form value from javascript to php using ajax request, which returns the result in XML format.

Everything looks working great for me in Mozilla FF, but in IE when I try to send the value in Arabic character set (UTF-8) it stops working though I added the following code part to my php:

http://dpaste.com/717863/

This part handles the values passed to php from the script and sets the encoding to UTF-8...though still Arabic is not working for me in IE case, but English is working fine.

Can anyone help me please

Comment: If it works in Firefox and not IE, it is very unlikely that the problem is with your PHP script, unless IE is not passing the data in as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```