# Ajax doesn't work in IE if URL contains Arabic character

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

In my Blogger website I load posts from JSON feed, The JSON link looks like this.

```
    http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LABEL NAME?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5
```

This is the code that I use to get posts from the URL above.

```
    $.ajax({url:""+window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
    +"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+LABEL NAME
    +"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5",
    type:'get',dataType:"jsonp",success:function(data){}
```

The problem is that when I change 'LABEL NAME' with an Arabic label the posts didn't load. I tested it with English label and it's working fine, but I have problem with Arabic ones. I have tried this to decode URL but it's not working.

```
    $.ajax({url:""+window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
    +"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+encodeURIComponent(LABEL NAME)
    +"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5",
    type:'get',dataType:"jsonp",success:function(data){}
```

This is a [live demo](http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/) of the problem.

Comment: Please define _not working_ in your case. Do you get a 404 from the server or some other error? I think this might be a problem with mapping encoded URLs on the server-side rather than being a client-side problem.

Comment: The problem is the posts doesn't show up.
Note : The problem is just in IE.

Comment: There was a similar issue in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994759/arabic-text-doesnt-work-with-ie-jquery-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994759/arabic-text-doesnt-work-with-ie-jquery-ajax). See if that helps.

Comment: Yet another two similar posts for ie: 1) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750205/sending-arabic-characters-via-ajax-not-working-in-ie) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931560/solving-this-issue-of-sending-arabic-characters-using-ajax)

Comment: I tried every solution here in stack but they didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help though. IE was always a tough nut to crack for "special" cases. Which version of IE has the problem anyway?

Comment: The problem is in IE 9.

Comment: I know it's not ideal, but since you're using an existing platform, on which your control is limited, it might be helpful to just index the target blog posts so that you wouldn't have to pass uni-code chars inside a URI (if the platform allows to do so).

Comment: Can you post your url here with the arabic content?

Comment: Use encodeURI(); for the label. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578114/1462741

Answer (score 1):

IE has problems with not properly encoded URLS, it has also problems with simple `<a href` containing unencoded chars.

`LABEL%20NAME` instead of `LABEL NAME` should work.

With JSONP, jQuery generates a `<script src="http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LABEL NAME?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5">` which has the unencoded char in it.

Instead of `encodeURIComponent(LABEL NAME)`, use quotation marks:

```
encodeURIComponent("LABEL NAME")
```

Important: Save your **files** `UTF-8` encoded.

[image] *(pic from [blog.flow.info](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/))*

**Example which works in IE**  (copied from Firefox+Firebug):

[image]

Comment: your solution works if I add the label manually but LABEL NAME is a variable that it take label from user inputs.

Comment: @Masked Variable names cannot contain whitespaces

Comment: I know that, I use "LABEL NAME" to explain to the reader that this variable is responsible for bringing the name of Category in my template I use "pl" (Means for post label).

Comment: @Masked so when you use `encodeURIComponent(pl)` it should work ;S

Answer (score 0):

In your live demo, removing

```
.shortext {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

From the css makes it look OK in IE for me. The div with id="recent" and class="recent shortext" seems to have different markup in FF.